# Transpose of compact operator is compact

Tags: operator-theory, solution-verification

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces. $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is compact and $T^*:Y^*\rightarrow X^*$ is its transpose. Let $B$ be the unit ball in $Y^*$ and $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since the image of the unit ball in $X$ under $T$ is totally bounded there are finitely many elements $x_1,\dots,x_n$ with norm less than $1$ such that for all $x$ in the unit ball there is some $i$ with $||Tx-Tx_i||<\epsilon$. Now for each such $i$ the set $\{(\phi(Tx_1),\phi(Tx_2),\dots,\phi(Tx_n)):\phi\in B\}$ is (totally) bounded. So there are finitely many $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_k\in B$ such that for each $\phi\in B$ there is an index $j$ with $\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}|\phi(Tx_i)-\phi_j(Tx_i)|<\epsilon$. Now consider the elements $T^*(\phi_1),\dots,T^*(\phi_k)\in T^*(B)$. For any $\phi\in B$ we get a $j$ as above and then $$||T^*(\phi)-T^*(\phi_j)||=||\phi\circ T-\phi_j\circ T||=\sup\limits_{||x||<1}|\phi(Tx)-\phi_j(Tx)|$$
And for each $x$ with $||x||<1$ we have (an index $i$ and) $$|\phi(Tx)-\phi_j(Tx)|\leq|\phi(Tx)-\phi(Tx_i)|+|\phi(Tx_i)-\phi_j(Tx_i)|+|\phi_j(Tx_i)-\phi_j(Tx)|$$
$$\leq ||\phi||.||Tx-Tx_i||+|\phi(Tx_i)-\phi_j(Tx_i)|+||\phi_j||.||Tx_i-Tx||<3\epsilon$$

Comment: Yes, good to be explicit about _totally_ bounded...